# ¿Cómo devolver varios String de acuerdo al valor del int?

Tags: java, android, string

he estado averiguando sobre cómo devolver varios `String` de acuerdo al valor del `int` que se ha pasado, pero no encontré información alguna. Por ejemplo, supongamos que el valor del `int` es 3. Lo que que quiero hacer hacer es devolver un String 3 veces básicamente. ¿Tienes alguna idea? Gracias.

Comment: si es el mismo String podes concatenarlo en uno solo,de ser diferentes devuelve un Array de String

Comment: Depende de a que te refieras con devolver varias veces el string? te refieres a un array? a uno abajo del otro? o simplemente concatenarlos? Aun asi tu solucion se encuentra en un FOR